# Laravel Eloquent - Filter is ignored when returning results

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to return a (JSON) string of a specific user with his/her posts. However the Post model contains several columns that aren't of interest for API implementations and I want to exclude these columns from the result.

Why does the following still return no columns at all in the Posts relation 
I've tried multiple ways of retrieving specific columns on the Post model.

```
$result = User::with([
    'posts' => function($q) {
        $q->addSelect('title', 'tag');
    }])
    ->where(['api' => 1, 'id' => $id])
    ->first(['id', 'username', 'role']);

return $result;
```

dumping

```
$q->get()
```

shows exactly what I want, however the returned $result includes none of the columns in the Post model.

My Laravel version is 5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing `addSelect` to just `select`

```
$result = User::with([
    'posts' => function($q) {
        $q->select(['title', 'tag', 'user_id']); // You might have to also include `user_id` here
    }])
    // ->where(['api' => 1, 'id' => $id]) change this
    ->where('api', 1)
    ->where('id', $id)
    ->first();

return $result;
```

Because addSelect is adding items to an existing select, rather than specifying what you actually want in the select.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've actually tried this already and the response is the same.. Also I've edited my question (the output is actually empty)

Comment: I also didnt know your `where` could work like that... I thought you had to have multiple wheres. see updated answer

Comment: did you add the `user_id` column to your select?

Comment: Yes!! adding the user_id column did the trick. Legend! I have changed addSelect to select and added the user_id to that same select. It works now.

Comment: Also the ->where(['api' => 1, 'id' => $id]) construction is still intact :)

Comment: Just nitpicking here but user_id is included in the posts relation, is it possible to filter this out in the returned result aswel?